# Xcode 8 cocoapods abort trap: 6

Tags: cocoapods, xcode8, abort

```
localhost:PodTest3 haiwang$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing MBProgressHUD (0.9.2)
Installing Masonry (1.0.2)
Generating Pods project
Abort trap: 6
```

After upgrading to Xcode 8, `cocoapods` doesn't work anymore. I have tried to uninstall and install, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Cocoapods didn't generate wrokspace files

Comment: I had try many ways, until update my ruby(2.0.0) to 2.2.4. Maybe I thought this BUG is caused by old ruby.

Comment: I tried all of the above method to solve this issue.
In the end, I solved this issue by updating the xcodeproj with gem.

Answer (score 188):

For me, I solved this issue by uninstalling and then again installing CocoaPods with `--pre` with the command

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

**Update**

CocoaPods has released version 1.2.0, so you can now install using

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And you will get version 1.2.0 installed

Comment: This is the trick - `cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1` got installed above `cocoapods-1.1.1` -> `Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62)`

Comment: Exactly @WarrenBurton... :-)

Comment: I had the same problem. This fixed it. Version 1.0.1 was uninstalled (let it uninstall all versions, let it remove executables). Version 1.2.0.beta.1 was installed. Thank you, Haider!

Comment: BTW: I'm on Sierra. Ruby version is 2.0.0p648.

Comment: Worked fine on macOS Sierra 10.12.1. Current installed version for the time being is `1.2.0.beta.1`

Comment: For completeness of preferred tools, equivalent command line `brew install --devel cocoapods`

Comment: confirming only thing that solved for me was updating to the beta

Comment: @haider_kazal Nothing will happen for other projects, is n't it?

Comment: @himanth this commands will update the Cocoapods, not the project's pod file... So nothing will happen to projects

Answer (score 41):

You can easily solve this issue using the follow command:

```
gem update cocoapods
```

Comment: I see, you have the latest version then. Uninstalling it and Installing it again may solve the problem. It worked for me because I had an older version of cocoapods.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

If the simple uninstall by @haider_kazal doesn't work like it didn't for me, try to install RVM with ruby 2.5.5, then purge CocoaPods completely:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem uninstall cocoapods-core
gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate
gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
gem uninstall cocoapods-plugins
gem uninstall cocoapods-search
gem uninstall cocoapods-stats
gem uninstall cocoapods-try
gem uninstall cocoapods-trunk
```

And then install once again:

```
gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Answer (score 7):

Uninstall the cocoapods and reinstall:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods

gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: i had to add sudo in front of this answer like raiders answer. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this error when I installed cocoapods with brew.

running `brew uninstall cocoapods`
then `sudo gem install cocoapods` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all this things but none of them worked for me, this one did:

```
sudo gem update
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue with Cocoapods 1.1.1 on rvm ruby (tried 2.2.4p230, and 2.0.0p648 which is the equal to system ruby version), with Xcode 8.1 (8B62), macOS 10.12.1 (16B2657), and only thing that helps me is updating to Cocoapods 1.2.0.beta.1, or using system ruby:

```
$ rvm system do pod install
```

and of course if you don't have cocoapods installed in system gemset:

```
$ sudo rvm system do gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: I used `rbenv` to install `2.0.0-p648`and it worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This should definitely help you.

However I'm not pleased with the previous version of Cocoapods as it has a few other issues.

```
 gem uninstall cocoapods
 sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it work using Cocoapods 1.1.1 with Xcode 8.1 on macOS 10.12.1 (the one with TouchBar support) by removing generated workspace, running `pod deintegrate` and running `pod install` again.

Comment: With macOS `10.12.2 (16C67)` and Xcode `8.2.1 (8C1002)` the problem is no longer occurring using Cocoapods `1.1.1` with RVM.

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect solution when you are receiving the **"Operation not permitted" error or xcode8 cocoapods abort trap:6**.

**Custom GEM_HOME**

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/Software/ruby
$ export GEM_HOME=$HOME/Software/ruby
$ gem install cocoapods
[...]
1 gem installed
$ export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Software/ruby/bin
$ pod --version
1.1.1
```

Comment: awesome @Harshal Wani Thanks, I got my solution through this

Answer (score 1):

Run this in the terminal:

```
sudo gem install xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 0):

It's problem with ruby in version `2.0.0` and cocoapods `1.1.1`, so if you won't use prerelease version of cocoapods, just update your ruby version for example with rvm:

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

**Remember**: After install of new ruby you need to install all gems one more time.

Comment: Hi, how did you figure out that? What is the problem with ruby 2.0 ?

Comment: I had this problem and after install newest version of ruby and install cocoapods one more time, problem just disappear. I have no idea what is the problem with ruby 2.0.0, I don't have time to investigate when it fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by updating the ruby with \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby.

Answer (score 0):

My fix, little bit less work: I removed the workspace and just run `pod setup` and `pod install` again.

No more warnings :)

Answer (score 0):

update your ruby version to 2.4 then uninstall cocoapods and install it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an using old version of cocoapods and an old version of xCode you may find after updating to new cocoapods version it complains about your Podfile syntax.

In this situation, another alternative to solve the problem is to keep using the old cocoapods version and set the path to the old xCode version so that cocoapods uses old xctools versions for workspace modifications.

i.e. don't update cocoapods (keep using old version - e.g. 0.39.0) and instead run this command to point to different Xcode version:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch "path to old version of Xcode.app"
```

Answer (score -3):

download xcode8-beta.

```
localhost:Applications haiwang$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
    localhost:Applications haiwang$ xcode-select -p /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer

Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `PodTest7.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
```

It is OK.