# Xcode8.1 cocoapods Abort trap:6

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

This is my pod file contents :

`pod 'Firebase/Core
 pod 'Firebase/Auth’
 pod 'Firebase/Database’
 pod 'Firebase/Storage'
 pod 'SDWebImage'`

The pods install but fail to cretae an xworkspace. It fails with Abort 6. I'm running Xcode 8.1 and on macOS 10.12.2 Beta. I have tried deleting and reinstalling the latest prerelease of pods. Any other solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution here works for me:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980096/xcode8-cocoapods-abort-trap6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40438232/589472)

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Comment: Changing the rvm to the latest version worked for me. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: That worked....