# no xcworkspace generated when using pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have created a new iOS project using Swift, and inside that project I created new file project --> Cocoa touch framework. I then went to my terminal, and executed the following commands:

```
pod init
open -a xcode podfile
```

I wrote the following in my podfile:

```
 platform :ios, '9.0'
 use_frameworks!
 target 'Halgat' do
 pod 'SwiftyJSON'
 pod 'Alamofire'
 pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 4.0'
 pod 'SCLAlertView'
 end
```

However no App.xcworkspace was created, what's my problem and what's wrong?

Here is how my folder looks:

[image: Xcode project navigator screenshot]

I ran `pod install` and the terminal outputted the following:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (4.2.0)
Installing AlamofireObjectMapper (4.0.1)
Installing ObjectMapper (2.2.2)
Installing SCLAlertView (0.7.0)
Installing SwiftyJSON (3.1.3)
Generating Pods project
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: run `pod install`

Comment: as i said in my comment, i run it.and it runn successfully.please check the image too, it just did not create xcworkspace

Comment: solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980096/xcode8-cocoapods-abort-trap6 thankfully solved it

Comment: Try running pod update, maybe it helps, not sure because I haven`t had that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must update your cocoapods using following command:

```
gem update cocoapods
```